# TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am working on node.js.
node.js version is v14.1.0.

KingInfo.js

```
"use strict";
const db_module = require('../DB/db');
    
(async function(){
  console.log("start");
  
  let sql = [];
  sql.push("SELECT count(*) as count");
  sql.push(" FROM dbname.tablename");

  let result = await db_module.query(sql.join(""));
  console.log("result="+Object.entries(result));
  console.log("end");
}());
```

db.js

```
"use strict";
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'databasename'
});

async function query(sql){
  console.log("query.1");

  await connection.connect((err) => {
    console.log("connection.connect");
    if (err) throw err;
  });

  return connection.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
    console.log("connection.query.1");
    if (err) throw err;
    return result;
  });
}

module.exports = {
    query: query
}
```

I run `node KingInfo.js` then got the errors and logs:

```
start
query.1
(node:15792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: 

Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at E:\XXXXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXX\KingInfo.js:33:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15792) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
connection.connect
connection.query.1
```

it seems stopped at this code: `let result = await db_module.query(sql.join(""));` because it doesn't have log for the code: `console.log("result="+Object.entries(result));` and the rest.

I am new to async process, promis, await/async things. So my code related to async might cause this errer?

I should have asked in another post but I am not confident the code in the db module, either. If you have some advice for me how to fix it properly, please tell me.

Comment: A couple of things,

1) Why you want to create SQL query in an array and join to send, and not a simple string?
2) Every time your query method is going to create a connection to the database and there is no releasing of same, it will choke your database and crash system with some load, Use connection pooling
3) Add a try-catch in your query method, so the error can be more specific.

rest seems good, just give a try making a query in a string if possible

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked 8 month ago, but I will provide some advise for people who face such a problem. Well,

1. [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) library is **callback-based-only**, it's methods not return promises, if you need promises, then consider something like [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql).
2. If you look at your output, you will see that after **unhandledRejection** error there are 2 lines printed, which are the `console.log`'s from your **connect** and **query** callbacks, so, in the end, your query is performed successfully.
3. The thing with this error is that, object that is returned by **connection.query** call, contains some property, that can not be converted to primitive value, due to either being torn from the simple object prototype chain(i.e. something like ({}).__proto__ = null), or there are invalid overrides of **Symbol.toPrimitive** method or both of **toString** and **valueOf** methods.
   Here is an example code with same error result:

   ```js
   const o = {}

   o.toString = undefined
   o.valueOf = () => ({}) // Must return primitive

   const returnedByQuery = { o }
   console.log("result " + Object.entries(returnedByQuery))
   ```

   And here is the same result as you have:

   ```
   /home/xxx/index.js:7
   console.log("result " + Object.entries(returnedByQuery))
                      ^

   TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
       at Array.join (<anonymous>)
       at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
       at Array.join (<anonymous>)
       at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxx/index.js:7:23)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
   ```

   When you performing concatenation, it will try to convert each entry - **[key, value]** tuple to string, for this it will try to convert given **value** to string, and here it will fail.
4. And finally, if you need to get promises from callback based methods:

```js
const p = new Promise(
    (res, rej) => connection.query(sql,
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) return rej(err)
            return res(result)
        }
    )
)
// then you can await it(In async functions)
await p
```